# trying to update new posts with jquery ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to get the content of the url and append it to my div, every 10 seconds, I'm quite new to javascript and really have no idea why this is not working, any light shed would be great.

my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function get_new_posts(){
    var new_posts = $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/ajax/get_latest_posts/",
                        dataType: "html",
                        cache:false,
                        async: false
                    }).success(function(){
                        setTimeout(function(){get_new_posts();}, 10000);
                    }).responseText;

    $("#posts_container").append(new_posts);        
});
};
```

I know the page generating the posts is working as I can see them in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should execute your function:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      get_new_posts();
 });

function get_new_posts(){
var new_posts = $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/ajax/get_latest_posts/",
                    dataType: "html",
                    cache:false,
                    async: false
                }).success(function(){
                    setTimeout(function(){get_new_posts();}, 10000);
                }).responseText;

$("#posts_container").append(new_posts);        

};
```